# Is there a way to make this Wordle-like SQL query using advanced BigQuery features?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, wordle-game

I'm trying to do some word/letter analysis using BigQuery using rules similar to Wordle.

You know the drill:

- letter present but in other position
- letter in correct position
- ⬜ letter not present.

I have a working query but I'm not really satisfied for three reasons:

1. It doesn't look too BigQuery-y
2. For large sets of words, the query doesn't scale well
3. Extending to, say, 7 letter words would look really, REALLY, **REALLY** horrible, messy and any number of nasty adjectives could easily describe it

The way I'm doing this vaguely reminds me of recursive CTE, but sadly those are totally elusive to me...

Making it faster is not really a concern but I'm wondering if there's a more advanced/elegant way (for lack of a better term) to accomplish the same result: recursive CTE, TVFs I guess using Javascript UDFs is an option, but I'd like to stay away from them and instead explore an SQL-only alternative.

This is the ugly query:

```
with words as (
    select normalized_word as word, 'solution' word_type
    from unnest(["SCAPE","PETER","SMACK","MAMMA"]) as normalized_word
),
split_word as (
    select word,letter,word_type,
    row_number() over(partition by word) as pos
    from words, unnest(split(word,'')) as letter
),
check_correct as (
    select a.word word1,any_value(a.word_type) as word_type,b.word word2,
     string_agg(if(a.letter=b.letter,'',a.letter),'' order by a.pos) w1,
     string_agg(if(a.letter=b.letter,'❌',b.letter),'' order by a.pos) w2,
     sum(if(a.letter=b.letter,1,0)) c,0 p
    from split_word as a, split_word as b
    where a.word <> b.word
    and b.word_type = 'solution'
    and a.pos = b.pos
    group by a.word,b.word
),
check_first as (
    select word1,word_type,word2,c,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,1,1))>0,p+1,p) p,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,1,1))>0,concat('',right(w1,4)),w1) w1,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,1,1))>0,
      concat(
        left(w2,instr(w2,substring(w1,1,1))-1),
        '❌',
        right(w2,length(w2)-instr(w2,substring(w1,1,1)))),
      w2) w2,
    from check_correct
),
check_second as (
    select word1,word_type,word2,c,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,2,1))>0,p+1,p) p,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,2,1))>0,concat(left(w1,1),'',right(w1,3)),w1) w1,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,2,1))>0,
      concat(
        left(w2,instr(w2,substring(w1,2,1))-1),
        '❌',
        right(w2,length(w2)-instr(w2,substring(w1,2,1)))),
      w2) w2,
    from check_first
),
check_third as (
    select word1,word_type,word2,c,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,3,1))>0,p+1,p) p,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,3,1))>0,concat(left(w1,2),'',right(w1,2)),w1) w1,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,3,1))>0,
      concat(
        left(w2,instr(w2,substring(w1,3,1))-1),
        '❌',
        right(w2,length(w2)-instr(w2,substring(w1,3,1)))),
      w2) w2,
    from check_second
),
check_fourth as (
    select word1,word_type,word2,c,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,4,1))>0,p+1,p) p,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,4,1))>0,concat(left(w1,3),'',right(w1,1)),w1) w1, 
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,4,1))>0,
      concat(
        left(w2,instr(w2,substring(w1,4,1))-1),
        '❌',
        right(w2,length(w2)-instr(w2,substring(w1,4,1)))),
      w2) w2,
    from check_third
),
check_fifth as (
    select word1,word_type,word2,c,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,5,1))>0,p+1,p) p,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,5,1))>0,concat(left(w1,4),''),w1) w1,
    if(instr(w2,substring(w1,5,1))>0, 
      concat(
        left(w2,instr(w2,substring(w1,5,1)) - 1),
        '❌',
        right(w2,length(w2)-instr(w2,substring(w1,5,1)))),
      w2) w2, -- for completeness
    from check_fourth
),
final_result as (
    select word1 as guess, word_type as guess_type, word2 as solution, c as correct, p as present, 
    length(w1)-c-p as absent,
    regexp_replace(w1, r'([A-Z])', '⬜') as wordle, w1, w2 
    from check_fifth
) 

select *
from final_result
order by guess
```

The result looks like this:
[image: All 12 rows]

Note some interesting edge cases with repeated letters in the guess word: 2, 3, 5. My **ugly** query manages this by "consuming" matched letters in solution and replacing them with ❌ to avoid further matches. That's the sole purpose of `w2`: avoid more than one match.

**Update**

Mikhail's solution *almost* works, but fails when guess word has repeated letters:
[image: Almost works!]

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach  - will work for any number of letters

```
with words as (
    select normalized_word as word, 'solution' word_type
    from unnest(["SHAPE","PETER","TAPES","JUMBO","NINJA","MAMMA"]) as normalized_word
), pairs as (
  select t1.word as guess, t2.word as solution
  from words t1, words t2
), greens as (
  select guess, solution, x, offset, color
  from pairs t, unnest(array(
      select as struct x, offset, if(x=y, '', '⬜') color
      from unnest(split(guess, '')) x with offset 
      left join unnest(split(solution, '')) y with offset 
      using(offset)
    ))
  where guess != solution
), yellows_temp as (
  select guess, solution, x, color
  from pairs t, unnest(array(
      select as struct x, '' color
      from unnest(split(guess, '')) x with offset as pos1
      join unnest(split(solution, '')) y with offset as pos2
      on x = y and pos1 != pos2
      group by x, color
    ))
  where guess != solution
), yellows as (
  select guess, solution, x, '' color 
  from yellows_temp y
  left join (
    select guess, solution, x
    from greens
    where color = ''
  ) g
  using (guess, solution, x)
  where g.x is null
)
select guess, solution, 
  countif(g.color = '') correct, 
  count(distinct if(g.color = '⬜' and y.color = '', y.x, null)) present,
  string_agg(if(g.color = '⬜' and y.color = '', '', g.color), '' order by offset) as wordle,
  string_agg(if(g.color = '⬜' and y.color = '', '', if(g.color = '', '', g.x)), '' order by offset) as w1
from greens g
left join yellows y 
using(guess, solution, x)
group by guess, solution
-- order by guess, solution
```

with output

[image]

Leaving w2 for you - should be relatively simple using above as a starting point :o)

Comment: This is brilliant Mikhail! I'm dissecting your query to fully understand your approach. It's so much more elegant!

Comment: Hi @mikhail-berlyant!
Upon closer inspection of the results, I noticed some weird results: SOCES - GUISE - ⬜⬜ -> shoud be ⬜⬜⬜, it's matching the second S in guess word when solution only has one S. PETER - SHAPE - ⬜⬜ -> shoud be ⬜⬜⬜, it's matching the second E in guess word when solution only has one E. TIFFS - OFTEN - ⬜⬜ -> shoud be ⬜⬜⬜, it's matching the second F in guess word when solution only has one F
In my approach, I "consume" letters in solution with ❌ to avoid matching more than once.
Do you think this is fixable on your approach?

Comment: it is not absolutely not clear (for me at least) what exactly rules are related to that issue - so I am leaving it up to you (or someone else interested) to address :o)

Comment: Hehehehe... The rules are the same as Wordle. I've accepted your solution because it's way more elegant than mine even if it's off for some pairs. I'm adding some more columns to the yellow_temps table to see if I can fix it... Thanks Mikhail, it's always nice to read your answers!